# The difference between react.development.js and react.production.js files via CDN

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, cdn, production

What is the difference between react.development.js and react.production.js files via CDN ?
Can someone please explain elaborately ?

I don't understand what does the term "via CDN" means here. CDN (content delivery network ) in react helps in setting up faster development environment, but what does it means in context of these 2 files ?

Comment: The production version will be optimized in a few ways--smaller file size by minimizing variable names and removing white space, etc--whereas the development version will remain readable, might include source maps, etc., making it better for debugging and development usage. Functionally they're the same.

Answer (score 2):

In development mode, we can enable and utilize React developer tools, devtools profiler, debugging environment attached with source code. We can utilize various functionalities such as Hot Module Replacement, diagnostics so that development environment will help to debug code.

In production mode, compression and minification of Javascript and other resources happens to reduce size of the code which is not the case when it comes to development mode. Performance will be much faster in production mode when compared to development mode.

Answer (score 0):

**react.development.js** - More developer friendly, readable, will take more size. 
**react.production.js** - Minified code that is not developer friendly as it focused on decreasing in file size, code efficiency.

**CDN** is the Content Delivery Network that provides you with the respective JS file online.

Answer (score 0):

**Development Environment:** react.development.js
*****Debugging Support:***** This file includes extra warnings and error messages to help developers identify and fix issues during development.

***Code Size:*** Larger file size due to the inclusion of development-specific tools and warnings.

***Performance:*** The development version is optimised for providing more helpful information and tools rather than being focused on minimal file size or performance.

**Production Environment:** react.production.js
***Minimised Code:*** This file is optimised for production use by removing development-specific warnings and tools, resulting in smaller file size.

***Performance:*** It is tuned for better runtime performance in production environments.

***Error Messages:*** Error messages are more concise, as the development-specific warnings are stripped away.

Answer (score -1):

The React library provides two versions of its JavaScript files: react.development.js and react.production.js. These files serve different purposes and are typically used in different stages of the development and deployment process. When serving these files via a Content Delivery Network (CDN), there are a few key differences between them:

File Size: The react.development.js file is typically larger in size compared to react.production.js. The development version contains additional code, comments, and debugging information that aids in development and troubleshooting. On the other hand, the production version is optimized for performance and has undergone various optimizations, including minification and removal of unnecessary code, resulting in a smaller file size.

Performance: The production version (react.production.js) is optimized for performance and is typically used in production environments. It includes various optimizations, such as dead code elimination, to make the React library run more efficiently. These optimizations help reduce the overall bundle size, improve runtime performance, and enhance the user experience.

Error Messages: The development version (react.development.js) provides more detailed error messages and warnings compared to the production version. This helps developers identify and diagnose issues during the development process. The development version includes additional checks and warnings to provide useful information when something goes wrong. However, these additional checks and messages are not included in the production version for performance reasons.

When using a CDN, it's common to load the development version (react.development.js) during development and debugging stages. This allows developers to take advantage of the detailed error messages and warnings provided by the development version for easier debugging. However, in production environments, it is recommended to use the production version (react.production.js) for better performance and reduced file size.

It's worth noting that the specific file names (react.development.js and react.production.js) may vary depending on the version and release of React you are using.